# Error using click event in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have my function call like this in HTML:

```
<a href="" ng-click="registerCallbacks(event)" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Angular Call back</a>
```

And I am trying to pass a event and print it out but I am getting an error:

`Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': The event provided is null.`

```
//Call back events
    $scope.registerCallbacks = function (event) {
        console.log("registerCallbacks not working");
        console.log(event);
        window.dispatchEvent(event);
    };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your HTML you need to pass `$event` (you're missing the `$` at the front) like so:

```
<a href="" ng-click="registerCallbacks($event)" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Angular Call back</a>
```

Comment: Is it because of angular? normally in plain javascript we pass only `event` right?

Comment: @kittu yup, just an angular thing! :)